# Permissions problem when selecting image from gallery on Android

Tags: android, xamarin, permissions

I'm starting with Xamarin to be able to create an app that runs both on iOS and Android.
The first thing I wanted to do is to click a button -> Open Gallery -> Select image -> Display selected image on a Image label

The current content of MainPage.xaml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HelloWorld" x:Class="HelloWorld.MainPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        <Label Text="0" x:Name="lbl_counter" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" FontSize="Large"/> 
        <Image x:Name="img_selected" Source="" /> 
        <Button Text="Click Me" Clicked="Handle_Clicked" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

I'm using Plugin.Media so, when the button gets clicked I run this code:

```
async void Handle_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e){
    lbl_counter.Text = (++counter).ToString();

    await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();
    if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsPickPhotoSupported){
        await DisplayAlert("no upload", "picking a photo is not supported", "ok");
        return;
    }

    var file = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync();
    if (file == null)
        return;

    img_selected.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(file.GetStream);
}
```

After a bit (a lot) of effort I managed to get it working on iOS.
But I can't get it working on Android. It keeps complaining about permissions.
I already followed all I could think of from:

- https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/89455/how-to-loading-images-from-gallery
- https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin
- https://blog.xamarin.com/requesting-runtime-permissions-in-android-marshmallow/

Any idea?

---

Adding information from the comments

Comment 1:

I don't get a (visible) stack trace in Xamarin.
I get this if I copy from the error window:

```
Plugin.Media.Abstractions.MediaPermissionException: Storage permission(s) are required.
```

In the Output Window I can see:

```
Does not have storage permission granted, requesting.
Storage permission Denied.
```

---

**CODE**

*MainPage.xaml.cs*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Plugin.Media;
using Plugin.Permissions;
using Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions;

namespace HelloWorld
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        private int counter;
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        async void Handle_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            lbl_counter.Text = (++counter).ToString();

            /******************************/
            try
            {
                var status = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Storage);
                if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
                {
                    if (await CrossPermissions.Current.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationaleAsync(Permission.Storage))
                    {
                        await DisplayAlert("Need Storage", "Gunna need that Storage", "OK");
                    }

                    var results = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(Permission.Storage);
                    status = results[Permission.Storage];
                }

                if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
                {
                    await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();
                    if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsPickPhotoSupported)
                    {
                        await DisplayAlert("no upload", "picking a photo is not supported", "ok");
                        return;
                    }

                    var file = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync();
                    if (file == null)
                        return;

                    img_selected.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(file.GetStream);
                }
                    else if (status != PermissionStatus.Unknown)
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Storage Permission Denied", "Can not continue, try again.", "OK");
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                //...
            }
            /******************************/

        }
    }
}
```

*MainPage.xaml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HelloWorld" x:Class="HelloWorld.MainPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        <Label Text="0" x:Name="lbl_counter" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" FontSize="Large"/> 
        <Image x:Name="img_selected" Source="" /> 
        <Button Text="Click Me" Clicked="Handle_Clicked" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

*MainActivity.cs*

```
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace HelloWorld.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "HelloWorld", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Plugin.Permissions.PermissionsImplementation.Current.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
    }
}
```

*AndroidManifest.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.gedons.HelloWorld">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="27" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <application android:label="HelloWorld.Android">
        <provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

_file_path.xml_

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-files-path name="my_images" path="Pictures" />
    <external-files-path name="my_movies" path="Movies" />
</paths>
```

Comment: What is the actual Exception/Stacktrace that you are getting?

Comment: I don't get a (visible) stack trace in Xamarin.
I get this if I copy from the error window:
    Plugin.Media.Abstractions.MediaPermissionException: Storage permission(s) are required.

In the Output Window I can see:
    Does not have storage permission granted, requesting.
    Storage permission Denied.

Comment: I've to say, there's no pop up asking for the permissions to be given...

Comment: You need to include permissions in your app, first in the manifest AND you need to perform runtime check if perms have already been granted, and if not request them from the user.

Comment: You could use the [PermissionsPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin) to request runtime permission on android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Permissions problem when selecting image from gallery on Android

Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app. You should [requesting permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html?hl=en-us) at runtime.

System permissions are divided into two categories, normal and dangerous:

- Normal permissions do not directly risk the user's privacy. If your app lists a normal permission in its manifest, the system grants the permission automatically.
- Dangerous permissions can give the app access to the user's confidential data. If your app lists a normal permission in its manifest, the system grants the permission automatically. If you list a dangerous permission, the user has to explicitly give approval to your app.

`READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is divided in to [Dangerous permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html#normal-dangerous), so  you should checking this permissions manually for API level 23 and above.

---

For `Xamarin.Forms` project, you could use the [PermissionsPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin) to request this permission in `Xamarin.Forms` at runtime.

- [Here](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin/tree/master/samples/PermissionsSample) is the official sample of `PermissionsPlugin`.
- [setup of this PermissionsPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin#setup)

Simple usage here, add this code in your `MainActivity`:

```
public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Permission[] grantResults)
{
    PermissionsImplementation.Current.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```

Request permission when you need it:

```
try
{
    var status = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Storage);
    if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
    {
        if(await CrossPermissions.Current.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationaleAsync(Permission.Storage))
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Need Storage", "Gunna need that Storage", "OK");
        }

        var results = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(Permission.Storage);
        status = results[Permission.Storage];
     }

     if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
     {
         //Permission granted, do what you want do.
     }
     else if(status != PermissionStatus.Unknown)
     {
         await DisplayAlert("Storage Permission Denied", "Can not continue, try again.", "OK");
     }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Stil no :(

Actually, I forgot I had that plugin already (part of the experiments). I've put the code you suggested and after debug:

if (await CrossPermissions.Current.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationaleAsync(Permission.Storage)) // this if statement fails

After this:
status = results[Permission.Storage]

status is Unknown

There's no popup requesting the permissions

Comment: @Nahoot, that' wierd, it works fine on my side. Could you please post more detailed codes? or maybe share a basic demo that can reproduce the problem through online repo

Comment: I currently don't have a repo to put the code on. But I've put it in the initial question. Let me know if any file is missing... I think all is there...
I'm really out of ideas...

Comment: Interesting (or maybe not) experiment. I changed the target version to 22 and it worked. Then went back to higher versions and it continued to work.
I then cleaned the project and the emulator and tested again. And it failed again.

Comment: @Nahoot, did you install the [Current Activity Plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin) as the [PermissionsPlugin document](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin) said?

Comment: It worked! I had tried to install the Current Activity already before but it failed due to incompatible dependencies. Then I figured out it has to be added to the Android part of the project only. I was trying to add it to the overall project. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Android M you have to grand other apps such as (gallery) a storage permission, i.e the gallery needs to save the picked image into the provided URI path.

follow the steps here:
https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2012/08/07/granting-content-provider-uri-permissions/

Comment: Hi Hassan, thanks for the information. But I'm using Xamarin which works slightly differently...

Comment: I see. I think there is something in Xmarin to deal with such URI permission. 
take a look at this 
https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Content.Context.GrantUriPermission/